# How to create "subsets" as a result from a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Let's suppose that I've got as a result from one query the next set of values of one column:

```
    Value
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
8   H
9   I
10  J
```

Now, I would like to see this information with another order, establishing a limit to the number of values of every single subset. Now suppose that I choose 3 as a limit,the information will be given like this (one column for all the subsets):

```
   Values
1  A, B, C
2  D, E, F
3  G, H, I
4  J,
```

Obviously, the last row will contain the remaining values when their number is smaller than the limit established.

Is it possible to perform a query like this in SQL? 
What about if the limit is dynamic?. It can be chosen randomly.

Comment: Yes. [read this](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)

Comment: SQL tables and results sets are no ordering unless a column explicitly states the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table dee_t (id int identity(1,1),name varchar(10))
insert into dee_t values ('A'),('B'),('c'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('g'),('H'),('I'),('J')


;with cte as
(
select (id-1)/3 +1 rno ,* from dee_t
) select rno , 
(select  name+',' from cte where rno = c.rno for xml path('') )  
from cte c group by rno
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using few calculations with row_number, like this:

```
select 
  GRP,
  max(case when RN = 1 then Value end), 
  max(case when RN = 2 then Value end), 
  max(case when RN = 0 then Value end)
from (
  select 
    row_number() over (order by Value) % 3 as RN, 
    (row_number() over (order by Value)+2) / 3 as GRP,
    Value
  from Table1
) X 
group by GRP
```

The first row_number creates numbers for the columns (1,2,0,1,2,0...) and the second one creates numbers for the rows (1,1,1,2...). Those are then used to group the values into correct place using case, but you can also use pivot instead of it if you like it more.

If you want them into same column, of course just concatenate the cases instead of selecting them on different columns, but beware of nulls.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42b21a/1)

Comment: Ok @JamesZ, thanks a lot for your reply. But, what about if the Limit is dynamic?

Comment: @d2907 If it's dynamic (and you want the results in one column), you can do it using xml path trick, and ordering the rows using the id, something like in user3864233's answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your reply. Finally I've got a Solution with the help of Rajen Singh

This is the code than can be used:

```
WITH CTE_0 AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT column_A_VALUE AS id
FROM Table
WHERE column_A_VALUE IS NOT NULL
),  CTE_1 AS 
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN, id 
    FROM CTE_0
    ),  CTE_2 AS
        (
        SELECT RN%30 GROUP, ID
        FROM CTE_1
        )SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ','''+CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(20))+''''
                                FROM CTE_2
                                WHERE GROUP = A.GROUP
                                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') IDS
                                FROM CTE_2 A
                                GROUP BY GROUP
```